command about find for delete file or folder application
I can use command list below to delete files or folders, but would it be deleted directly, not in the trash? Is there parameter which is for delete file directly?
find / -name .DS_Store -exec rm {} + 
find . -name .DS_Store -type f -delete


Do you seek affirmation of your understanding of how these commands work, or are you trying to solve an actual problem (and if yes, which one specifically)?

The commands you specified will delete the files permanently, that is, they won't be recoverable from the trash bin.
To send files to the trash bin from the terminal use a command line tool called trash.
You can install it with brew as follows:
brew install trash
